# Activate Click and MouseDown events at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to create a form where the user selects one of 2 radio buttons, "fast" and "slow", then presses a "go" button on the form. It should work as follows:

- When "fast" is selected and "go" is pressed, the user needs to continue holding down the button in order to make the player move and the player stops when the user releases their finger from the button. For this, I am using the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events.
- If "slow" is selected, the user can only move one step at a time, regardless of how long the button is held down. for this, I am using the `Click` event.

To test this concept, I put a `MessageBox` in the `Click` and `MouseDown` events to see how they work together. When I click on the button, however, I am only seeing the `Mousedown` event get triggered, regardless of which radio button is selected and the `Click` event is only triggered when the go button is in focus and I press enter.

How can I make it so that both events get called simultaneously (and then I can put the respective `if` statement in to differentiate between "fast" and "slow" radio buttons)? (The button is wired up to these events by double-clicking on their respective handler in the design window, not hardcoded).

```
private void go_button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Mousedown"); //  Doesn't show in console window in Release mode, still trying to solve this

    MessageBox.Show("Mosuedown");
}
private void go_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("go_buttonclick"); // Doesn't show in console window in Release mode, still trying to solve this
    Console.WriteLine("go_buttonclick"); //  Doesn't show in console window in Release mode, still trying to solve this
    MessageBox.Show("go_buttonclick");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your description of the behavior for the `Click` event. Note that the `Click` event will be triggered after the user releases the mouse button (is that what you want?) or if the button is clicked in any other way (e.g., using the keyboard).

Comment: You probably don't need the `Click` event anyway. Just use something like `if (fast.Checked) { StartMoving(); }` under `MouseDown` and `if (fast.Checked) { StopMoving(); }` under `MouseUp`, and then you can have an `else` block either under `MouseDown` or `MouseUp` (you decide) where you call `MoveOneStep();`.

Comment: There is no "Console" window in WinForms.  Use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...);` and look in the Output window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, I could do it that way. Wasn't sure if there was an explanation for why only one of the events gets triggered on the mouse click or if it was just a visual studio quirk.@41686d6564

Comment: I see that now @HansPassant, thanks. Just tried it again removing one of the MessageBoxes and it displayed the other 2 events!

Comment: @LarsTech I still cannot see anything in the output window, do I use "Show output from:" Build, Build Order, or SourceControl - git?

Comment: Visual Studio menu: View - Output

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was doing wrong, both events are being triggered at the same time, but the MessageBox in the MouseDown event wasn't allowing me to see the Click and MouseUp events also being triggered. When I turned off the MouseDown MessageBox, the other 2 MessageBoxes appeared, thanks!